# Find first occurrence of ID in query results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Looking for a little help on this Oracle (11g) query...

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT id, test_date 
  FROM test_data 
 WHERE id IN (7,27,28,32,34,44) 
 GROUP BY id, test_date ORDER BY test_date ASC;
```

Which gives me the following

```
ID / TEST_DATE
---------------
27 / 16-AUG-06
44 / 18-AUG-06
28 / 19-AUG-06
44 / 23-JUN-08
27 / 27-JUN-08
28 / 27-JUN-08
07 / 21-APR-09
07 / 11-MAR-10
44 / 02-OCT-10
27 / 08-OCT-10
34 / 04-APR-11
07 / 11-APR-11
07 / 18-MAR-12
32 / 30-JUN-13
```

What I'm looking for is the following results

```
ID / TEST_DATE
---------------
27 / 16-AUG-06
44 / 18-AUG-06
28 / 19-AUG-06
07 / 21-APR-09
34 / 04-APR-11
32 / 30-JUN-13
```

Basically the first occurrence for each ID

Comment: Do you really want the first occurrence for each ID, or rather the first date for each id? Your test data happens to be sorted by date, so in this case there is no difference, but this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, min(test_date)
  FROM test_data 
 WHERE id IN (7,27,28,32,34,44) 
 GROUP BY id 
 ORDER BY 2 ASC
;
```

Comment: Tried that, but I get a strange 'Not in GROUP BY expression' error, which from what I can see, says I need test_date in my GROUP BY (which seems very wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, (select t2.test_date from test_data t2 where t2.id = t1.id and rownum = 1) test_date
  FROM test_data t1
 WHERE t1.id IN (7,27,28,32,34,44) 
 GROUP BY t1.id  ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

Seems to do the trick